# Why the added speech in John Huston's "The Dead"?

Tags: book-adaptation, the-dead

John Huston's beautifully haunting film of James Joyce' short story "The Dead", from *Dubliners*, is so faithfully rendered as to be almost a perfect replica in film of the story itself.

But there is one speech at the dinner table which is not in the story and I've never been able to discover why. I believe it was delivered by the Irish-American guest. Why was it added to the film?